# Mixing mvc on webform

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, webforms

I follow this [link](http://media.wiley.com/assets/1539/15/professionalaspnet35mvc_chapter13.pdf) to mix mvc on webform.
I added reference of :

1. System.Web.Routing
2. System.Web.Abstractions
3. System.Web.Mvc

and modify my web.config as per documentation.

But in web form `Html.RenderPartial` ,`Html.ActionLink` are not recognize.I got a error:

`'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<object>' does not contain a definition for 'RenderPartial' and no extension method 'RenderPartial' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<object>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

May I missing any reference or I am in wrong way.MVC is totally new for me . Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have to make sure you're using the correct namespace. Since these methods are defined as extension methods you need to make sure you put the correct using namespace:

If this is in a web form, you need to add this on top of the page:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" %>
```

If it's in a razor view you need this:

```
@using System.Web.Mvc.Html
```

Comment: I import namespace but still got a error .There is not any actionlink.I have .ascx control.Any idea.Thanks for reply.